# no puedo aplicar estilos a resolucion tablet en landscape

Tags: html5, css3, responsive, mediaqueries

No puedo aplicar los estilos a un `article` en el mediaquery de tablet landscape. Me coge los estilos del mediaquery de resolución desktop. con mi tablet en horizontal el párrafo esta casi abajo no se ve el icono de flecha. En portrait se ve bien en la tablet. En desktop se ve bien también. He modificado el código muchas veces y no consigo solucionarlo.

```css
@media (min-width: 767px)  and (orientation : portrait){
  #shufle  {
    
    line-height: normal;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    //top: 35%;
  }
 #shufle .read-on 
   {
      margin-top:100px;
      padding-bottom:800px;

   }
  #shufle p 
  {
    margin-top: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 30px;
  }
}


@media screen and (min-width : 767px) and (max-width : 840px)  and (orientation : landscape){
   
   #shufle p
   {
      margin-top: 200px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 30px;

   }
  #shufle .read-on 
   {
      margin-top:350px;
      padding-bottom:300px;

   } 
   
 }
 
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
  #shufle p 
  {
   margin-top: 450px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }

#shufle .read-on 
 {
    margin-top: 300px;
    padding-bottom:80px;
  }
  
  }
```

```html
 <article id="shufle">
  <div class="container">
   
  
  <p class="fading-texts text-center">
   
   lorem impsum lomrem.
  </p>
 
  <p class="read-on">
   <a href="#about" class="goto">
   <span class="goDown">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-cog-white"></i>
   </span>
   <span class="htxt">Read on </span>
   </a>
  </p>
 </div>
</article>
```

Comment: ¿Tal vez el ancho de la tablet en modo landscape no está entre 767 y 840? Verifica aquí: http://mqtest.io/

Comment: no es eso. ya he modificado el 840 por 1280 en landscape y lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Estuve haciendo pruebas y tu problema está relacionado con una mala configuración del viewport. Normalmente deberías tener algo así en tu `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

En caso que no lo tengas, el navegador asume un ancho predeterminado por cada "fabricante", en Chrome es 980px.

Comment: si ya la tenia asi.

Comment: Proporciona más información entonces, porque no es posible reproducir tu problema, a mí me funcionan bien tus estilos.